# Fix invalid link targets after changing drive letter of 'Program Files' folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, links, drive-letter

I have a second `Program Files` directory on another partition because I can't store all of them on my SSD. So the default location is `C:\Program Files`, but some programs I'm not using too often were located at `F:\Program Files`.

At first I did not notice that the second partition's letter was `F:` and I started installing stuff, but then I saw it and changed it to `D:` which is what I wanted. However, now probably some links and stored path strings point to files on the former `F:` drive which is now really on `D:`. A specific example is a broken entry in the "open with" dialogue for .iso files.

How can I easily scan the registry (and whatever else important locations) for paths targeting the old drive letter `F:` and fix them to point to `D:` now? Using Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Simplest solution just install those programs again.  Far easier then attempting to scan your registry for the incorrect path since the registry editor does not really have a good search and replace function.

Comment: Well, actually I now just used `regedit.exe`'s "Search" function and manually performed the "Replace" part. Now my fingers are hurting... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working with the registry is risky, and I highly suggest to avoid this method. Since it might cause unstoppable system errors.**

Two Methods can solve your problem, but both of them needs to reinstall your programs.

**1st Method** is to reinstall your programs to the correct folder destination. (As [@Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) suggested in his comment) and continue using your system in your way.

**2nd Method** is to reinstall your affected programs to `D:\Program Files` and then move all `C:\Program Files` contents to `D:\Program Files` and then use [Symbolic Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680(v=vs.85).aspx) to redirect `C:\Program Files` to `D:\Program Files`. This will insure that any program will call `C:\Program Files` it will be automatically redirected to `D:\Program Files`, even if you install a new program and use the default destination `C:\Program Files`, it will automatically install its content in `D:\Program Files`, so you don't need to change the destination on every program. This will let your SSD breath by freeing some spa

[Useful Article](http://www.tested.com/tech/windows/39-using-symlinks-in-windows-for-fun-and-profit/)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Symlinks, I did not know that Microsoft finally adopted them from the UNIX world. I guess I'll make heavy use of them :)

Comment: The problem is, Windows protects certain files in there and even the folder is Read-Only and even after trying to take ownership of it I still get `Access Denied` on certain operations.

Answer (score 2):

You yourself said they were stored in F:\program files,  it wouldn't be that many items in the registry if you used that as the search,  unless you moved it after, and not installed it there. Registry search has no problems with colon or spaces.
 The same thing would apply to searching for text within/containing shortcuts , although finding a few shortcuts for installed programs and correcting them should not be trouble.

That leaves the installers pointer to the install location, some installers would store that in the registry, some would not.
EX: Some install/uninstall "logs" would have multiple file path & name for even every file item that was placed, without correcting that all that style of uninstaller would not uninstall.
There are many types of installers, searching both the registry and every file :-O should get you most the way there.

There are probably other things, and things related to windows 10 that, are not listed here.  I would probably leave them there, and use D for a backup OS or something :-)  next install change it then.

Comment: I cleaned up most of the registry entries "by hand" now (ouch, my fingers...) and now I'll probably just wait and leave it as long as it works...